# AWS SSM not recognized as a command

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have installed AWSCLI and session-manager on my Ubuntu instance and confirmed the installation based on the guides. I also configured my instance using aws configure.
Now when I use

```
aws ssm start-session --target [target_instance_id]
```

But I get the error below:

> usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
>   To see help text, you can run:
>     aws help
>     aws  help
>     aws   help
>   aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are....

Which tells me ssm is not configured properly. How can I resolve this?

Comment: It sounds like you have a really old version of the aws CLI tool installed.

Comment: @MarkB This is what I get with aws --version:
aws-cli/1.14.44 Python/3.6.8 Linux/5.0.0-36-generic botocore/1.8.48

Comment: I think you were right. I've been using v1 and not v2. v2 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update awscli using this command

```
sudo pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Answer (score 0):

I had both CLI v1 and v2 installed. Using `aws` defaulted to v1, which doesn't support what I needed to do.